# How to declare assembly function with dynamic arguments in C++ like in C

Tags: c++, c, windows, assembly, winapi

I have some C code and I want to port it to c++, the problem is that in C++ I can't use an assembly function due to it's dynamic use

C version

```
extern asmFunc(); // C function prototype version

//actual use example
asmFunc(var1,ptr2,HANDLE); 
asmFunc(ptr4,var2,NULL,eg ...); //everything works
```

C++ version

```
extern "C" VOID asmFunc(); // C++ function prototype version

//actual use example
asmFunc(var1,ptr2,HANDLE); // E0140 too many arguments in function call
asmFunc(ptr4,var2,NULL,eg ...); // E0140 too many arguments in function call
```

The Assembly function is declared in a separate asm file and it uses direct syscalls from ntdll.dll's functions, that's why it requires dynamic arguments

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `...` in the argument list to specify the function is a [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) taking unspecified arguments, eg:

```
extern "C" VOID asmFunc(...); // C++ function prototype version

//actual use example
asmFUNC(var1,ptr2,HANDLE);
asmFUNC(ptr4,var2,NULL,eg);
```

Comment: Ok, but now how do i do the same thing with the return type?
Instead of VOID, something dynamic

Comment: @Damnson There is no such thing as a variadic return type in C or C++. What does it return? Your C code declares a function that returns `int`.

Comment: Well actually i think i don't need variadic return type as i need only `NTSTATUS` return type, i thought that i might need it as in C version there is no return type specified

Comment: So by default it returns `int` in C?

Comment: @Damnson that is correct.

Comment: Is the calling convention for ... always the same as the calling convention with the same arguments explicitly declared?

Comment: @user253751: For x86, yes, the mainstream calling conventions are designed to work that way.  Especially Windows x64.  (x86-64 System V requires callers of variadic functions to set AL= # of XMM args, so that's an extra `xor eax,eax` before a call.) Variadic functions also trigger the default argument promotions, so narrow types extend to `int`, but in x86 (including x86-64) still get passed the same way, and the actual bits of the narrow type keeps its value since x86 is a 2's complement machine.  But `float` promotes to `double`, so it makes it impossible to pass an actual `float`.

Comment: @user253751 using `...` in the argument list only works with the `__cdecl` calling convention in 32bit builds. `__cdecl` is typically the default convention that most C/C++ compilers use when no convention is specified, but that can usually be changed in the compiler settings.

Answer (score 0):

**You can have multiple labels at the same address.**  You could have multiple prototypes with different names that all happen to have the same address (and thus implemented by the same machine code).  In your `.asm` file, you put:

```
global foo_int, foo_long, foo_float   ; NASM syntax for putting these in the symbol table
foo_int:
foo_long:
foo_float:
     your code goes here
     ret
```

You could also do this with assembler directives to create aliases for a symbol, like GAS `.set foo_long, foo`.

You can think of this as multiple names for the same function, or as other functions whose implementation is to fall through into the real function, as an optimized tailcall where you've even optimized away the `jmp` by making them contiguous in the asm.

---

Or using [a GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels), declare multiple C or C++ names that all use the same asm symbol name.  The compiler-generated `.obj` will have every call-site referencing the same symbol name.  (Which you're setting fully manually, so even without `extern "C"` there's no name mangling and no leading underscore unless you choose one.)

```
// GNU C or C++;  compatible with the mainstream compilers other than MSVC
int foo_int(...) asm ("foo");
long foo_long(...) asm ("foo");
float foo_float(...) asm ("foo");
```

See it in action [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgGykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAHKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFJdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BXIFVNQJ1DQTFkTFxibb1jc25bcM9faXliQCUtqhexMjsHAD06wDUAOIRcltuWySH1mcAzBZbW2gsyUyO0fRbAO6ECFsECJhbLExhCgIxEwrBuqDudDiCmOXzinwQhi2AFkhAA1NwmDQAQTCBC2/FQAH1cRAAHTkuZbJgKFhbCDmMwEhlzEyXTFY2gCYD41BEzlGMkUqk0ukMplmMwstnYqich48omy1APQWkynU2n0iXiyWsqzY9m4z6YQEQFkAdn1WOu1yNBDuW1ZABEFYSlSqwBwmJ7SFsuFKrTatsCCMsGJ87nr2SZzU72RwFrROABWXh%2BDhaUioTgYyzWLYKJYrH7mc48UgETQJhYAaxA53OpIbzZbrcCSY4kjTVaznF4ChAGgrVYWcFgSFuyUhZAoEEn05QBiMUg0Q5otAIUMo0R70TCDQAnpxy7c2IIAPIMWhHjO8LB/IziW%2BkfDAmoANxNPcwqmqXk3x68LimAdpmtB4NExCHh4WA9kCeAsIBCyykwwAKKieCYC857JIwgEyIIIhiOwUgEfIShqD2uhcPohjGGclj6BBA6QAsqDJI4AgDhwAC0gLoM6wAMF4DEWGYGjXDx57nFsPF/CsCDOgoNYHgYNY/HJTB7s6LAKP2IHVJxfgQK4YytEEDDoNMAzxDRqTpEZZl6PZhQMNZZSDDRHRGd0oyeC0ejebUIy9GE/QebZkx%2BTk5mAlMYUzJ5CyFssqx6ECmBrDwiYpt2z7ZhwqgJP4PH%2BJINxLtyUikhoNV0rmViMVsuCECcpY0Yc4JTvQxCOmYZZzLwla3nMtb1o2raTc27acF2pDppmBX9oOw4jaQY6ICgXXTuQlDzj1IDAFwEp8HQm7EAOEA7s%2Be7MMQN4nuCZ4EJe149vedFPpmr6GXgn7cZmP5/gB3BAYIIE9uBkHQRgayZvBiGg8hBhoRhWE4XhoNkUR4ikfwgiKCo6jProZi0UYKCiUx0QsWaWYcZk3F8QQAnnE6ph5pY4mydJsnycgils8pqlMOpkl/NpbO6fp9hGS4llOTRIQJTZzkFI5/njPkDmZO5sxeQZnQML5TSa7Fhs%2BSFeueVFpsxYFVsqxFEjJUWaU0RlWUJvouXzT2BVFSVZVbMAyDIH6ZikmY9VU81%2BBEL17W%2Bh4EI9X15ySkNI5jQ2TZTZNPudnli19rYK3DVoo2F2Yxe8Etq2Vwsn4XZkICSEAA%3D) with clang and GCC, noting that `return foo_float('a', 1);` in the C++ source compiles to a `call foo` in the compiler-generated asm.  (Godbolt compiles for Linux normally, but I used `-mabi=ms` to get GCC to use the Windows x64 calling convention.)

---

If this was in a separate DLL, each name would get resolved separately, wasting a bit of space for multiple DLL import entries (whatever Windows calls the functions pointers that are equivalent to the GOT in Linux dynamic linking.)  The GNU C `asm("name")` way doesn't have this downside, as there's only one asm symbol name.
But if you're just linking this `.asm` file into the same executable or library as the C++ callers, separate symbol-table entries get resolved and go away at build time, not every time you run.

---

You could have a full prototype (and name) for every different function signature.

**Or you could just have a name for every different return type,

using `extern "C" int foo_int(...);`** as Remy's answer shows.  Note that `(...)` will trigger the default argument promotions, e.g. `float` will promote to `double`, so it's impossible to pass an actual `float`.  (This is why `printf`'s "%f" conversion takes a double.)

The promotions are harmless and very cheap for integer, though, just sign- or zero-extending to `int`.  The mainstream x86 and x86-64 calling conventions were designed such that args are passed the same to variadic functions as they would be for a prototyped function with the same arg types (after promotion of float to double).  x86-64 System V requires callers of variadic functions to set AL = # of XMM args, a number from 0 to 8; without any FP or vector args, this means each call-site will get an extra `xor eax,eax`.  That's about as cheap as a 2-byte NOP, especially on Intel.

---

Assuming the return type is statically known for any given call-site, this should solve your whole problem.  If not, it's trickier!

**It wouldn't necessarily work to to return a `union`** and decide at run-time which return value to use.  Some calling conventions would return a pure `float` in a different register (e.g. xmm0) than they'd pick for a union with a `float` member.  Even for pure integer, a union of an `int` and a larger struct would get returned in memory, differently from a plain `int`.